# Eclipse:An internal error occurred during: "Loading Web Service DOM...".

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse 3.6 Helios version.I am working on it from last three months.But from last two days I am getting some error.
When eclipse started it is giving an error in this format:`An internal error occurred during: "Loading Web Service DOM...".
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreEMap$DelegateEObjectContainmentEList`

I am not getting how can suddenly error occurred.
After this if I do Ok and continue with eclipse I am getting error with eclipse import project 
for existing work space and svn check out. 
Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look in the [Error Log](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/views/error_log.htm) for the root cause. Search for this in the [bug database](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

Comment: I had a similar problem that this solved: http://dracoblue.net/dev/refreshing-workspace-to-recover-changes-crash/143/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After research a lot, I came to know that I my java version is degraded to 1.5.I dont know how it took place.So I updated my java version to 1.7 again.And this error is solved.

Comment: how is it related to java version . can u plz elaborate

Comment: @sam Still I am not able to find any reason for it, trick done by me was just a patch work and work successfully.